# How to copy backend data fetched from Parse to a backbone view variable?

Tags: javascript, parsing, backbone.js

I'm working on a backbone/node.js project when I need to get data from Parse and use the data elsewhere.

I planned to use $.post() to fetch the data(schools) and copy it to fetchSchools. but currently my code fails to copy schools to fetchSchools.

//inside the backbone view:

```
    this.fetchedSchools = [];
    var self = this;
    $.post('/schoolview', {}, function(schools) {
        for(var i = 0; i<schools.length; i++){
            self.fetchedSchools.push(schools[i]);
        }
    });

    console.log(this.fetchedSchools);
```

Comment: `$.post` is asynchronous, so the interpreter reaches your `console.log` before the `$.post` has completed (most likely). Put your `console.log` right after the `for` loop

Comment: @benhowdle89 I need to use fetchschools right after post completes. Do you have an idea of how I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: Anything inside `function(schools){ // here }` will be ran after `$.post` completes. Do it in here.

Comment: @benhowdle89 that seems good. But I need a way to copy the data and use it as a global variable. Which is pretty hard.

Comment: Showing some more context code would help get better answers/solutions to your issue!

Comment: Thanks Ben. I think I'll just do everything within the function for now.